# Print header information using awk every 20 lines

Tags: linux, bash

I have a big data project that has thousands of entries. The data has roughly 20 columns including cylinders, gas mileage, make, model etc. I'm using awk to output all the data. I have to organize the data into a nice table.

I'm using a script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read x
do
echo $x | awk -F ',' ' { print $1":"$2":"$4":"$7":"$8":"$10":"$11":"$12":"$22":"$24 } '
done
```

There will be title headings where the colons are. I need to repeat those every 20 lines and must have a line break after line 20 and the header. Also, the last line should output the number of entries.

I'm stuck on the last 3 things to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no point using the `while read` loop, and in fact it complicates things since it makes it difficult for `awk` to keep a count of the line numbers.  Try:

```
awk -F, 'NR % 20 == 1 { print "header columns" }
    { print $1,$2,$4,$7,$8,$10,$11,$12,$22,$24 }' OFS=: input-file
```